# How to access, sum and then pass specific values in a PostGres table to a method

Tags: c#, sql, database, postgresql, npgsql

I'm currently trying to write a **time and attendance system** that allows employees to check their overtime using a `postgre database` with `C# and NPGSQL`.

The problem is that neither SUM() nor GROUP BY seem to yield any results, just errors. Here is a small section of my table

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSuXL.jpg

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the sum of the worked_hours of each day instead of getting 2 or more smaller values per day. Once I got that, I want to get the sum of the worked_hours of all days and then get the overtime by  multiply 8 by the amount of unique days to then subtract them from the sum of the worked_hours.

Once all of that is done, I just need to somehow access the overtime value so I can then pass it to my DecimalToTime method.
My code looks as follows:

```
    namespace OvertimeCalculator
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public static string DecimalToTime(double time)
            {
                var getDecimalMinutes = time - Math.Floor(time);
                var decimalMinutesToTime = getDecimalMinutes * 60;
                return Math.Floor(time) + " Hours and " +   Math.Round(decimalMinutesToTime, 0) + " Minutes";
            }
    private DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    private DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var employee_ID = textBox2.Text; 
        try
        {
            var connstring = String.Format("Host=localhost;Username=postgres;Password=123456;Database=test");

            var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
            conn.Open();
              var sql = @"SELECT DISTINCT employee_id, worked_hours, name  
                        FROM hr_attendance  
                        WHERE name >= '20150801' AND name < '20161201'
                        AND employee_id = " 
                        + employee_ID + 
                        @"AND worked_hours != 0 
                        ORDER BY name";

            var da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);

            ds.Reset();

            da.Fill(ds);

            dt = ds.Tables[0];

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ErrorMessage)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ErrorMessage.ToString());
            throw;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: There is no cloumn worked_hours. do you refer to sum column? what exactly is the meaning of the value in this column?

Comment: That was an oversight on my part. With worked_hours I am refering to the sum column. I'll replace the picture immediatly

Comment: ... and the errors are? Show exact error text please.